# Why am I getting errors calling the opencl library from mono on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, opencl

I am getting an 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' error calling the opencl library from mono under ubuntu linux.

Environment:
Ubuntu Linux 16.04
GeForce GTX 960
packages:  
ocl-icd-opencl-dev
nvidia-opencl-icd-384
opencl-headers
clinfo
mono-complete

created a symbolic link for libOpenCL.so in /usr/lib from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu as it did not seem to be in mono's path.

clinfo sees the platform and appears to put out correct data for the card.

Code as follows:

```
using cl_int = Int32;
using cl_uint = UInt32;
using cl_platform_id = IntPtr;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("OpenCL.dll")]
    public extern static cl_int clGetPlatformIDs(cl_uint num_entries, [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] cl_platform_id[] platforms, out cl_uint num_platforms);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
        try
        {
            IntPtr[] platformIDs=null;
            cl_int result=0;
            cl_uint returnedPlatforms=0;

            Console.WriteLine("call");
            // determine how many platforms are available - call based in chronos docs.
            // running with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug and MONO_LOG_MASK=dll shows the dll is found
            // abends with 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'
            result = (cl_int)clGetPlatformIDs(0, null, out returnedPlatforms); 
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ERR: {0} Platforms {1}", returnedPlatforms, result));
        }    
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oops");
            string stack = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (ex != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                if (ex.StackTrace != null && stack == null)
                {
                    stack = ex.StackTrace;
                }
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            }
            if (stack != null)
                sb.AppendLine(stack);
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }

    static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oops deep");
        Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
    }   
}
```

Executing with the mono debug set as stated in the code results in:

```
call
Oops
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at (wrapper managed-to-native) TestOCL.Program:clGetPlatformIDs (uint,intptr[],uint&)
at TestOCL.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x40740d60 + 0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0 

End
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'OpenCL.dll'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 
'/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL.dll': 
'/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL.dll.so': '/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/libOpenCL.dll': '/usr/lib/libOpenCL.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/libOpenCL.dll.so': '/usr/lib/libOpenCL.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libOpenCL.dll': 'libOpenCL.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libOpenCL.dll.so': 'libOpenCL.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'OpenCL.dll': 'OpenCL.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL': '/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL.so': '/home/oxygen/configuration/libOpenCL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/libOpenCL': '/usr/lib/libOpenCL: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library '/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'OpenCL.dll' ('/usr/lib/libOpenCL.so').
Mono: Searching for 'clGetPlatformIDs'.
Mono: Probing 'clGetPlatformIDs'.
Mono: Found as 'clGetPlatformIDs'.
```

The 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' is caught in the normal exception handling.

The call attempts to get the number of available platforms and follows the Khronos documentation.

I can't find any reason for it to not work, and can find no references to a similar problem.  Can someone please provide a direction/solution?

Comment: You probably need to import ` [DllImport("OpenCL")]` instead. (no .dll)

Comment: The logging shows that it has found 'OpenCL.dll' as /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so so I don't think that's it but I will give it a try.

Comment: You might want to try to initialize platformIDs, just to see if that's what's causing this NullReferenceException

Comment: Turns out the NVidia driver did not support the full OpenCL spec.  clGetPlatformIDs called with 0 caused the problem. It should still return the number but freaks instead.  I have changed my call to use 1, and catch the exception if it fails, thereby assuming none exist.  If the return value indicates more than one I repeat the call with the correct number.  Frustrating to have the spec. followed.